# Associate XML with XML-Schema anywhere on system

Tags: xml, xsd

I know it's possible to associate an XML-file with a DTD anywhere on the system.

```
    <!DOCTYPE xml SYSTEM "dtdfile.dtd">
```

I would like do the same with XML-Schemas. So the computer should search at least one drive on its own. Is that possible and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.acme.com/foo
                          http://www.acme.com/foo.xsd" .../>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how this is supposed to work. I tried <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="schema schema.xsd">